# Paginated query by using Dapper and SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have the following database table:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Horse] 
(
    [Id]      INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [HorseId] INT NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Shows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

and the `Riders` table:

```
TABLE [dbo].[HorseRider] 
(
    [Id]           INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]         NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [HorseRiderId] INT NOT NULL,
    [HorseId]      INT NOT NULL,
    [Birthday]     DATETIME          

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Cast] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

What I am trying to perform is paginated queries through Dapper.

For example let's say that for each page I want to get 10 horses and for each horse the riders that have been riding it. So what I did is creating a Data model for the result of such query:

```
public class HorseWithRiders
{
    public int HorseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<Riders> Rider { get; set; }
}

public class Rider
{
    public int RiderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

And for Dapper will most likely be something like:

```
var result = connection.QueryFirst<List<HorseWithRiders>>(...query...);
```

Now.. maybe there is some flaw with the way I structured things..but I don't manage to get the right query. Could you help me finding a query that fits the data model that I created but at the same time the pagination? The combination of the 2 things is something I am struggling. The reason behind this structure of the Data is because I want to serve the result of this query through API as a Json that looks something like:

```
[
    {
        "HorseId" : 1,
        "Name" : Name,
        "Riders":[
            {
                "RiderId" : 21,
                "Name" : RiderName,
                "Birthday": 01/01/1990
            },
            {
                "RiderId" : 22,
                "Name" : RiderName,
                "Birthday": 02/02/1990
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "HorseId" : 2,
        "Name" : Name,
        "Riders":[
            {
                "RiderId" : 24,
                "Name" : RiderName,
                "Birthday": 01/01/1990
            },
            {
                "RiderId" : 25,
                "Name" : RiderName,
                "Birthday": 02/02/1990
            },
            {
                "RiderId" : 26,
                "Name" : RiderName,
                "Birthday": 02/02/1990
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
query:

```
select [Horse].Name, [HorseRider].Name, [HorseRider].PersonId, [HorseRider].Birthday, [HorseRider].HorseId from [HorseRider]
  JOIN [Horse] on [Horse].HorseId= [HorseRider].HorseId
  where [HorseRider].HorseId= @value 
  order by [HorseRider].Birthday desc
```

Comment: Have you looked into `Offset` and `Fetch`?

Comment: Why is `Rider.Birthday` a string?